# Instalando drupal 8, me han un error de 32 bits hasta el 2038

Tags: drupal, drupal8

he instalando el Acquia dev desk en Windows 10 junto con el git y el composer
todo fue bien hasta que verifico los requisitos del sistema.
La instalación me deja continuar pero me gustaría poder solucionarlo.
Creo que  recordar que los bytes se modificaban el al archivo php.ini pero no se si es el caso, antes  de tocar nada prefiero preguntar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para el primero tienes que instalar la versión 7.1 o mayor de php, supongo que estas utilizando WAMP, si pudieses nombrar cual es podríamos darte una respuesta más completa.

Para el segundo recomiendo que leas esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it).

Comment: hola Pipe!  Bienvenido y gracias por responder. Ten en cuenta que las respuestas tienen que tener más informacion, por ejemplo la del enlace explicalo en la respuesta. Si ese enlace se rompiera, la informacion que ella contiene desapareceria de tu respuesta. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo!